# Pytest: Module is not callable

Tags: python, pytest

I know there are other questions on SO about 'module' object is not callable, but it's not clear how my problem is an instance of those. I only got this error why trying out Pytest (new to pytest). Trying to run pytest gives me `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

my directory structure:

```
    --appDir
      |--main.py
      |--__init__.py
      |--toolsDir
      |    |--handler.py
      |    |--db.py
      |    |--__init__.py
      |
      |--testDir
      |    |--main_test.py
      |    |--__init__.py
```

A simplified version of my files:

**main.py**

```
from .toolsDir import handler

hdlr = handler.Handler()


def emp_exists(emp_num):
    res = hdlr.lookup_row(emp_num)
```

**handler.py**:

```
import time

from . import db

class Hanlder:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.check_if_ready()
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(5)
            self.check_if_ready()
    
    @log
    def check_if_ready(self):
        if not db.table_exists()
        ...
    def lookup_row(self, _id):
        ...
```

**main_test.py**:

```
import pytest

def test_lookup_row():
    from ..main import emp_exists
    emp_exists(123)
    ...
```

To me, it looks like the traceback is indicating the problem is with `def check_if_ready(self)` method in `Handler` class:

Traceback:

```
        def test_lookup_row():
    >       from ..main import emp_exists
    
    testDir\main_test.py:8:

    -

    main.py:19: in <module>
        from .toolsDir import handler
    toolsDir\handler.py:37: in <module>
        class Handler:
    -

        class Handler:
            def __init__(self):
                try:
                    self.check_if_ready()
                except Exception as e:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    self.check_if_ready()
    
            @log
    >       def check_if_ready(self):
    E       TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
    
    toolsDir\handler.py:55: TypeError
```

Comment: I don't see any imports for a thing called `log`. Where are you getting the `@log` name from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need delete `__init__.py` from root project directory. Because `__init__.py` indicates that directory where it's located is a package.

Also better to use not relative imports but from project root, e.g.:

```
# in main.py
from toolsDir.handler import Handler
hdlr = Handler()
...
# in handler.py
from toolsDir import db
...
```